# What is the purpose of Fame in Torchlight?

Tags: torchlight

Apart of the additional skill point gained on every fame level, is there any other purpose for this - practical or not?

Also, I reached the max fame level of 50 really early in the game which is quite disappointing.. every single Champion killed gives almost full fame level which is pretty insane - any reason behind this design?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you an additional retain a fame level each time you retire, but beyond that, there isn't much else.

What difficulty are you playing on? The lower difficulties are really easy and you may want to try changing it. I know Champions don't give me as much Fame as you describe on Very Hard or even Hard.

Comment: I'm playing the medium difficulty (normal? don't remember their syntax :)) and the fights are not easy but still - looks like too much fame.

Comment: Normal in Torchlight is actually quite easy, even for me, someone who wasn't well-versed in ARPGs at all. I suggest hard.